# read two tokenized files using multithreading in java

Tags: java

i need to read two tokenised files and to store into database using multithreading in java

Comment: Thats nice, but what is your question?

Comment: Isn't that a school exercise?

Comment: I would suggest you create a multi-threaded ExecutorService and add a task for each file you need to load (assuming they can be loaded concurrently)

Comment: You haven't said why you need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch two threads, one for each file, reading the file and inserting data into the database. Database built-in transaction support will ensure synchronization between threads when inserting data into the database.

An alternative solution is to use an ExecutorService to manage the threads and pass him to Runnables which will read the files and insert data into database.